# Github image's links downloaded instead of showing

Tags: image, github, preview

I have a group of .gif images in a Github repository, they all look perfect in a browser except two: they download instead.

These are right:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akidaniel/almacen/gh-pages/paillettes_html/images/3SKULLS.gif
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akidaniel/almacen/gh-pages/paillettes_html/images/HEART.gif

These are not:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akidaniel/almacen/gh-pages/paillettes_html/images/POCKET.gif
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akidaniel/almacen/gh-pages/paillettes_html/images/DISCO.gif

I don't see any difference in the links except the gif name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in [`pypa/warehouse` issue 5596](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/5596#issuecomment-475305959)

> The issue is that the **`Content-Type`** for this image is `application/octet-stream`.
>   Instead, it should be **`image/gif`**.
>
> I've submitted a ticket to GitHub for why the Content-Type of my gif image is mistaken to `application/octet-stream`.
>
> GitHub replied:
>
> > It seems we serve gif files under 5MB via `raw.githubusercontent`.
> >     **Any files over this size are served as downloadable `octet-stream` files**.
>
> It seems that there is nothing I can do but shrinking the gif image.

Check if, in your case, this is not a size issue in [`akidaniel/almacen/tree/gh-pages/paillettes_html/images`](https://github.com/akidaniel/almacen/tree/gh-pages/paillettes_html/images).

- [`gh-pages/paillettes_html/images/DISCO.gif`](https://github.com/akidaniel/almacen/blob/gh-pages/paillettes_html/images/DISCO.gif) is 11.7MB
- [`akidaniel/almacen/blob/gh-pages/paillettes_html/images/POCKET.gif`](https://github.com/akidaniel/almacen/blob/gh-pages/paillettes_html/images/POCKET.gif) is 12.6 MB

Comment: Great, I broke my head thinking of absolutely any possibility except the file size. I will fix the images. Thanks.